# Custom form adding extra field and in database table also extra field

Tags: 7, database

```
function countries_form($form, &$form_state,$id=0) {

if($id!=0){
 $result =  db_query('SELECT * FROM {countries} WHERE id = '.$id.'')->fetch();
// print_r($result);exit;

 $form['country_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => 'Country name',
    '#size' => 30,
    '#maxlength' => 30,
    '#default_value' => $result->country_name,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );

  }else{
  $form['country_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', //you can find a list of available types in the form api
    '#title' => 'Country name',
    '#size' => 30,
    '#maxlength' => 30,
    '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required 
  );
  $form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#title' => t('Description'),
    '#format'=> 'full_html',
    '#pre_render' => array('ckeditor_pre_render_text_format'),
  );
  }
  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

I am using above form for drupal 7 ...which inserting country name ..now i want add one more form fields which is description with some text editor.... I tried adding below code for textarea with editor..i was this in else part...

```
$form['body'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#title' => t('Body'),
    '#format'=> 'full_html',
    '#pre_render' => array('ckeditor_pre_render_text_format'),
  );
```

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDunG.png)

```
function countries_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

if(arg(2)!=0){

  $query = db_update('countries')->fields(array('country_name'=>$form_state['values']['country_name'],'description'=>$form_state['values']['description']))->condition('id',arg(2))->condition('country_name','%d');
 $query->execute();

 drupal_set_message(t('Country %name has been updated.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['country_name'])));
}else{
  $query = db_insert('countries')->fields(array('country_name'=>$form_state['values']['country_name'],'description'=>$form_state['values']['description']));
$query->execute(); 
 drupal_set_message(t('Country %name has been saved.', array('%name' => $form_state['values']['country_name'])));
 }

   //$form_state['redirect'] = 'mypages/table';
  }
```

**I was tried like the above insert and update..but not getting insert its showing error..when i submit...even the country_name also not updating if form submits well... my question is .. 1) i want insert new field description 2) country_name if exists need to update..**

Comment: What is "->condition('country_name','%d');", I think error is here.

Comment: that is not effecting...

Comment: in this query how to check existing country_name...if exists also its getting insert as new ..how to check ..........

Comment: I have no clue about arg(2) without menu code details. Can you please provide details to get all info? Always inserting means its executing "else" part only.

Comment: arg(2) for inserting values...

Comment: even in that that having status..i am not able to change the status by editing....

Comment: share your browser screenshot before and after form submit

Comment: where i can share screens

Comment: upload somewhere and share link here

Comment: Please try to avoid extended discussion in comments.  Edit details into the question itself.  Thanks!